# Using sockets in react+flask application

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm trying to implement sockets in my React+Flask application and am running into issues. When I start my backend server, I get a continuous loop of users connect. Then when I start the frontend, the users get disconnected. Any ideas on what the issue is? I was using this [guide](https://medium.com/@adrianhuber17/how-to-build-a-simple-real-time-application-using-flask-react-and-socket-io-7ec2ce2da977) as a starting point, but no differences in the code are jumping out at me. The only difference between what I'm doing is I'm using `Vite` instead of `Create React App`.

**Python packages**

```
bidict==0.22.1
blinker==1.6.2
click==8.1.6
dnspython==2.4.1
Flask==2.3.2
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
Flask-SocketIO==5.3.5
greenlet==2.0.2
gunicorn==21.2.0
h11==0.14.0
importlib-metadata==6.8.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
packaging==23.1
pyserial==3.5
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python-engineio==4.5.1
python-socketio==5.8.0
simple-websocket==0.10.1
six==1.16.0
Werkzeug==2.3.6
wsproto==1.2.0
zipp==3.16.2
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"*": {"origins": "*"}})
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')


@socketio.on("connect")
def connected():
    """event listener when client connects to the server"""
    print('-' * 25)
    print(f"Client has connected: {request.sid}")
    emit("connect", {"data": f"id: {request.sid} is connected"})
    print('-' * 25)


@socketio.on("disconnect")
def disconnected():
    """event listener when client disconnects to the server"""
    print('-' * 25)
    print("User disconnected")
    emit("disconnect", f"User {request.sid} disconnected", broadcast=True)
    print('-' * 25)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "socket-example",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.22",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.61.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.61.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.26",
    "prettier": "3.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.0"
  }
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'

// "undefined" means the URL will be computed from the `window.location` object
const URL =
  import.meta.env.MODE === 'production' ? undefined : 'http://localhost:5000'

const socket = io(URL, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
  },
})

export default function App() {
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(socket.connected)

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('connect', (data) => {
      console.log(data)
      setIsConnected(true)
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
      console.log(data)
      setIsConnected(false)
    })

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect()
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <p>WebSocket: {'' + isConnected.toString()}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```